# No items in Object Library Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

I keep having problems with XCode6 , I also tried to uninstall it and reinstall it.
Whenever I try to open it it keeps saying "No matches" and I cannot use any object.
I'm trying to start an iOS project!
[image: That's how it looks like to me]

Comment: I hope there is nothing in filter under the Object library.

Comment: Do they appear when you open a storyboard?

Comment: open storyboard it will come

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found that they appear if you open the xib file in the centre pane of the main window.  If the xib is open in a separate floating window nothing appears and you get 'No matches'

Comment: This also happens if you have split the window and have the storyboard on the right.