# XCode 6.1.1 "No matches" in Object Library

Tags: ios, xcode

Im trying to create my first iOS application.. following a book and the Apple developer resources. I'm having the same issue at least two other people have had and asked about but neither of those answers seemed to solve my problem..

1) how do you open the .xib file in the main window and not a floating window? 
2) I am not in the assistant editor

any help would be much appreciated..

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to bear any resemblance to its title... Is the title related?

Comment: I should have listed the other two threads with answers to the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28641328/xcode-6-object-library-is-empty-no-matches

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354956/no-items-in-object-library-xcode-6

Answer (score 0):

To open a .xib file in the main window, just single click it in the project navigator on the left. I suspect you're double clicking, which will result in a new window!

Comment: here is the thread.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28641328/xcode-6-object-library-is-empty-no-matches

Comment: Are you able to post a screenshot of your copy of Xcode, showing the error?

Comment: i found your email and sent it to you!